# È accettabile usare il presente indicativo insieme al condizionale di "potere" o di "volere" (in determinate situazioni)?

Tags: grammar, conditional-mood

La mia perpetua lotta per non massacrare la grammatica spagnola, e ormai quella italiana, mi ha costretto a sviluppare l'abitudine di abbinare il condizionale presente con il congiuntivo imperfetto. Di conseguenza, mi sorge spesso un dubbio quando sto formulando frasi come le seguenti:

> Se non vi piace, mi potreste suggerire qualcosa di meglio?
>
> Se non hai bisogno del trapano in questo momento, potrei servirmene?
>
> Se non c'è alcun ostacolo, vorrei cominciare appena possibile.

In tali casi, impiegare il congiuntivo imperfetto invece del presente indicativo sembra esprimere un'idea diversa (o forse un'idea alquanto incoerente...). Inoltre, il verbo al condizionale non si adopera come un condizionale vero e proprio bensì come una maniera di addolcire la richiesta.

Ho l'impressione che locuzioni di questo genere non costituiscano un errore flagrante—cioè, un errore che strazia gli orecchi di chi è madrelingua. Mi domando, però, se si tratti di un errore piccolo che susciterebbe qualche disapprovazione in un ambiente formale.

Comment: Dirò di più: potresti usare l'indicativo invece del condizionale nelle prime due; non nell'ultima che ha “volere”; non che il condizionale sia sbagliato. Il congiuntivo imperfetto nella subordinata è più formale.

Comment: Personalmente, non trovo niente di male nella sintassi. Mi strazia gli occhi solo quella lineetta (“—”). Negli incisi si usa questa “–”, ma a coppie; l'uso così è un anglismo della punteggiatura.

Comment: Le tre frasi non contengono errori, ma solo l’inesattezza del trattino e del verbo “servirmene” (nel secondo esempio, direi: «potrei usarlo io»?).

Comment: @DaG Molto interessante, grazie per avermi avvisato. Ho notato che la punteggiatura italiana è sorprendentemente conforme a quella inglese, ma questa differenza mi è sfuggita. Mi dispiace averti straziato gli occhi ;)

Comment: @egreg Riguardo alle prime due frasi, diresti che l’uso del condizionale suona più cortese e/o più educato?

Comment: Certamente più cortese.

Comment: No problem, Gallego, ci ho messo qualche goccia di collirio. Tra la punteggiatura italiana e quella inglese ci sono molte affinità ma anche varie sottili differenze. Per esempio, in inglese si abbonda con le virgole nei complementi di tempo (“In 1881, Poincaré developed...”, “For Poincaré, topology wasn’t just an intellectual game”), mentre in italiano non servono.

Comment: Alcune frasi pronunciate da Ferruccio (cioè, Dante Pratolini), il fratello dell'autore, nel libro che sto leggendo (Vasco Pratolini: *Cronaca familiare*) che, per il modo in cui è stato educato, usa sempre le buone maniere: «Se non ti dispiace, vorrei invitarti». «Potremmo dormire insieme, su un fianco c’entriamo tutti e due, se non ti dispiace».

Comment: Ma anche, come ha segnalato @egreg: «Se non ti dispiace, puoi farmi un prestito?».

Comment: @Charo La differenza è tra “vorrei” (dipende da chi parla) e “puoi” (dipende da chi ascolta). Fin da piccoli ci insegnano che “l'erba voglio non cresce nemmeno nel giardino del re”.

Comment: @egreg: Cioè, dire "voglio" suonerebbe molto maleducato, no?

Comment: @Charo Rivolgendosi a qualcuno, sì.